# How check if a site (not site collection) has sub sites in it? [Object Model]

Tags: 2007, site-collection, object-model, spweb

I am trying to figure out a way to check if a Site inside a Site Collection has sub sites in it.

To get sites inside a site collection, we can use the below code.

```
foreach (SPWeb siteobject in siteColName.AllWebs)
```

**But how to check if siteobject has sub sites in it.?**

Also, if it has subsites, then will it be treated as SPSiteCollection obejct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the count of int SPWeb.webs collection is greater than zero.

Comment: Yes, that was the required condition. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need [SPWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478651%28v=office.12%29.aspx), SubSite collection is SPWebCollection not SPSiteCollection, essentially a subsite is a SPWeb object

Also I think beside your requirement you should have a look at what really [SPWebApplication, SPWeb, SPSite](http://point2sharepoint.blogspot.in/2011/03/spweb-vs-spsite-vs-spwebapplication_29.html) represent

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am familiar with the above terms. The issue was a little confusion over a website having multiple subsite within.